# Gerar Lista a partir de BinaryFormatter Deserializado Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá estou criando um sistema de "save" para jogos e gostaria de saber como posso gerar uma lista a partir de um objeto `BinaryFormatter`? esse arquivo é formado a partir de 3 informações, e gostaria de gerar uma lista com esses valores, segue o códigos:
Criar o arquivo:

```
 public void Save(string userName, int HighScore)
{
   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   FileStream _file = File.Open(Application.dataPath + "/Save" + _filename, FileMode.Append);
   PlayerData _data = new PlayerData();
   _data.playername = userName;
   _data.typeScore = "points";
   _data.highscore = HighScore;
   bf.Serialize(_file, _data);
   _file.Close();
   Debug.Log("Save Criado!");
}
```

e para carrega-lo:

```
 public void Load()
{
   BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
   FileStream _file = File.Open(Application.dataPath + "/Save" + _filename, FileMode.Open);
   PlayerData _data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(_file);
   infoData = _data;
   _file.Close();
   Debug.Log(_data);
}
```

queria saber como gear uma lista com as informações contida dentro do save.

classe PlayerData:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData {
  public string highscore;
  public string playername;
  public string typeScore;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou usar?
`using System.Collections.Generic;`
`public static List<Game> savedGames = new List<Game>();`

A propósito, você está querendo criar uma lista com vários saves, ou quer colocar os dados do save dentro de uma lista?

Comment: é um save de scoreboard, quero colocar os dados do save dentro da lista.

Comment: Teu save e load estão funcionando conforme você esperava? Se sim, então agora é só pegar os valores que você recebeu no load e atribuir para uma lista.
`public static List<Placar> resultados` e  `resultados.add(Placar valor)`

Comment: sim ele esta funcionando normalmente, eu consigo recuperar apenas os últimos valores eu já tentei, porem não é possível converter um objeto do tipo `PlayerData` para uma `List<PlayerData>` diretamente, eu precisei listar os itens internos do save com `HasTable` para depois passa-los para a lista e pelo o que eu entendi isso ocorre porque meu Save não possui uma formatação de indexação, não é uma lista;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após quebrar a cabeça, não consegui resolver mediante a forma que eu precisei, porem a solução seria essa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

[Serializable()]
public class Lizard
{
public string Type { get; set; }
public int Number { get; set; }
public bool Healthy { get; set; }

    public Lizard(string t, int n, bool h)
    {
        Type =    t;
        Number =  n;
        Healthy = h;
    }
}
```

para serializar:

```
 var lizards1 = new List<Lizard>();
        lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Thorny devil",                1, true));
        lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Casquehead lizard",           0, false));
        lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Green iguana",                4, true));
        lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Blotched blue-tongue lizard", 0, false));
        lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Gila monster",                1, false));

        try
        {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.bin", FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            bin.Serialize(stream, lizards1);
        }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {

        }
```

para ler:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.bin", FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();

            var lizards2 = (List<Lizard>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
            foreach (Lizard lizard in lizards2)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}",
                lizard.Type,
                lizard.Number,
                lizard.Healthy);
            }
        }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
```

em outra palavras eu precisaria criar uma lista dos dos objetos que seriam salvos: `var lizards1 = new List<Lizard>();` e add `lizards1.Add(new Lizard("Thorny devil",1, true));` porem dessa forma não seria interessante para mim, minha solução foi conseguir um host online, criar uma base de dados criar 2 arquivos em php para envio e leitura de dados, e envia-los para o servidor, acessar esses arquivos através do jogo e criar a lista. aqui vão os codigos:

```
string _host = "http://ramses.freewha.com/";
string phpScore = "score.php";

 public void PegarScore()
{
    WWW scoreSite = new WWW(_host + phpScore);
    StartCoroutine(BuscarScore(scoreSite));
}

IEnumerator BuscarScore(WWW w)
{
    loading.color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
    yield return w;
    loading.color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 0);
    if (w.error == null)
    {
        resultadoRank = w.text.Split(","[0]);
        foreach (string nome in resultadoRank)
        {
            GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(playerScoreEntryPrefab);
            go.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);

            var outputName = Regex.Replace(nome, @"[0-9\-]", string.Empty);
            go.transform.Find("UserName").GetComponent<Text>().text = outputName;

            var outputPontos = Regex.Replace(nome, @"[a-z\-]", string.Empty);
            go.transform.Find("Scoore").GetComponent<Text>().text = outputPontos;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error ao Enviar: " + w.error);
    }
}
```